# reindent.py - Does not work from the command line

Tags: python-2.7, indentation

I have problems with indentation in Python. So I downloaded `reindent.py` to correct the indentation errors.

I installed reindent.py using the following command-:

```
pip install reindent
```

But I running it from the command line shows me the following error-:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/reindent", line 3, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reindent.py", line 92, in main
    check(arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reindent.py", line 118, in check
    if r.run():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reindent.py", line 177, in run
    tokenize.tokenize(self.getline, self.tokeneater)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 170, in tokenize
    tokenize_loop(readline, tokeneater)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 176, in tokenize_loop
    for token_info in generate_tokens(readline):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 357, in generate_tokens
    ("<tokenize>", lnum, pos, line))
  File "<tokenize>", line 127
    for w in transcript:
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I am running it with the following command-:

```
reindent -n test1.py
```

I thought `reindent` was supposed to correct the errors not show me where they occurred.

Comment: There is an IndentationError in `test1.py`. Fix the IndentationError and then `reindent.py` will work.

Comment: @unutbu isn't reindent.py suppose to fix the indentation error for me ? is there any way i can fix indentation errors automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

`reindent.py` changes tabs to spaces and can make irregular indentation a uniform 4-spaces. It does not attempt to catch or fix `IndentationError`s.

Consider this code which has an IndentationError:

```
def foo():
    print("Let's go")
  for i in range(2):   <-- IndentationError
      print('Peay')
```

---

It produces a similar error message to the one you are getting:

```
% reindent.py script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...          
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 170, in tokenize
    tokenize_loop(readline, tokeneater)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 176, in tokenize_loop
    for token_info in generate_tokens(readline):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 357, in generate_tokens
    ("<tokenize>", lnum, pos, line))
  File "<tokenize>", line 9
    for i in range(2):
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

---

Both

```
def foo():
    print("Let's go")
    for i in range(2):
        print('Peay')
```

and

```
def foo():
    print("Let's go")
for i in range(2):
    print('Peay')
```

are valid ways to fix the code. `reindent.py` (or the `tokenize` module that it
relies on) does not attempt to guess which one the coder intended. Thus,
`IndentationErrors` are `SyntaxError`s that at least sometimes require human
intervention to fix.